Useing v-data-table with 'how-select' and 'return-object' dosen't work correctly
Im trying to use Vue3, Vuetify v-data-table component.Without 'return-object' all works fine, im getting id, but i want to get user objects. So the problem is when i click on select all checkbox first time i get such proxy array:
Example
0:Proxy(Object) {id: 1, name: 'testFirst testSecond', phone: 'xxxxxxxxx'}
1:Proxy(Object) {id: 2, name: 'testFirst testSecond', phone: 'xxxxxxxxx'}


and after click to unselect im get this, but expect empty array:
0:{id: 1, name: 'testFirst testSecond', phone: 'xxxxxxxxx'}
1:{id: 2, name: 'testFirst testSecond', phone: 'xxxxxxxxx'}
2:Proxy(Object) {id: 1, name: 'testFirst testSecond', phone: 'xxxxxxxxx'}
3:Proxy(Object) {id: 2, name: 'testFirst testSecond', phone: 'xxxxxxxxx'}
;

But, if put my computed properties value to ref, it's will work fine.
  <v-data-table
    v-model="selected"
    :headers="headers"
    :items="items"
    show-select
    return-object
  ></v-data-table>
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
const usersList = ref([
  {
    id: 1,
    attributes: {
      name: {
        firstName: "testFirst",
        secondName: "testSecond",
      },
      phone: {
        mobile: "xxxxxxxxxx",
      },
      dates: [
        { id: 1, start: "24.03.2024", end: "25.05.2024" },
        { id: 2, start: "21.03.2024", end: "23.05.2024" },
      ],
    },
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    attributes: {
      name: {
        firstName: "testFirst",
        secondName: "testSecond",
      },
      phone: {
        mobile: "xxxxxxxxxx",
      },
      dates: [
        { id: 3, start: "24.06.2024", end: "25.07.2024" },
        { id: 4, start: "21.06.2024", end: "23.07.2024" },
      ],
    },
  }
]);
const search = ref("search");
const selected = ref([]);

const items = computed(() => {
  if (usersList.value.length) {
    return usersList.value.map((item) => {
      return {
        id: item.id,
        name: `${item.attributes.name.firstName} ${item.attributes.name.secondName}`,
        phone: item.attributes.phone.mobile,
      };
    });
  } else {
    return [];
  }
});
const headers = computed(() => {
  if (items.value.length) {
    const keys = Object.keys(items.value[0]);
    return keys
      .map((key) => {
        return {
          title: "some title",
          value: key,
        };
      })
      .filter((item) => item.value !== "id");
  } else {
    return [];
  }
});

// works fine
// const itemss = ref(items.value);
// const headerss = ref(headers.value);

</script>````

Im trying to use checkbox in v-data-table. Select all must return all users, and after unselect it's should be empty array


You are using computed that always returns a ref, but as you are generating a new items list using usersList that was resulting in the issue of ref being unwrapped.
Instead just return the usersList if it has some data instead of creating the object again.
const items = computed(() => {
  if (usersList.value.length) {
    return usersList.value;
  } else {
    return [];
  }
});


but if i need to map usersList.value? it's can be array with different objects like : {id:,attributes:{
name:{
firstName:'firstname', secondName:'secondmae'}, phone:{mobile:'some phone'}}};
and i need computed property that will return array of { id: 1, name: "firstName secondName", phone: "some phome" },

Can you add all possible patterns of the list that needs to be displayed?

change usrsLis data. I need just display name and phone.
